# what files do I need in my GAE project?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth, openid

I am trying to use [SimpleAuth](https://github.com/crhym3/simpleauth) in my google app engine project and it seems pretty simple but I wanted to see what files I actually need in my project.  Right now my project directory looks like this:

```
src/
  main.py
  app.yaml
  index.yaml
  #these three are the SimpleAuth ones
  simpleauth/
    __init.py__
    handler.py
  httplib2/
  oauth2/
```

Do I need the entire SimpleAuth folder or are those two files all I need?  On the GitHub site it simply says to put the SimpleAuth subdir in the root but the main file is named SimpleAuth too.

Thanks!

Comment: You seem to have three underscores for the `__init__.py`. Is that intentional?

Comment: @Blender ah that was just a mistake in copying it over, just fixed it.  good eye there.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the docs it says thats all you need so you should just go ahead and try it to see if it works

Comment: haha thanks for the encouragement.  I wasn't that timid though and I have tried it.  I haven't gotten it working but I am trying to figure out the layout.  Mostly I am curious why there is this huge upload.py file: https://github.com/crhym3/simpleauth/blob/master/upload.py and it isn't used...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `simpleauth`, `httplib2` and `oauth2` is all you need. You could also start from a working [example app](https://github.com/crhym3/simpleauth/tree/master/example) and modify it as you pleased.

upload.py is a script to upload code change lists for a review on http://codereview.appspot.com (whenever want to contribute with a new feature or a bugfix). You don't need it if you just want to use the lib.